# jquery disable selectable grays out the element

Tags: jquery, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm trying to use a button to turn on and off the .selectable behaviour for a div on my page. I can do this using these commands:

```
$('#selectable').selectable({disabled: true})
```

or

```
$('#selectable').selectable("option", "disabled", true)
```

The functionality works as intended, but the only problem is that it grays out the entire element that was selectable. Enabling selectability removes the grayed-out look, but every time i disable the selectable it grays out.

Does anyone know how to disable selectability as an attribute without graying out the whole element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just destroying the selectable `$( "#selectable" ).selectable( "destroy" );` and when you need it back `$( "#selectable" ).selectable();`